# Recibo Malformed access_token: null en API MercadoPago

Tags: php, api, mercadopago

Éste es el código que estoy usando (realizado a partir del [ejemplo que proporcionan en la web de mercadopago](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/use-mercadoenvios/shipping-calculator/)):

```
require_once ( 'mercadopago.php');
$mp = new MP('xxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$params = array(
    "dimensions" => "30x30x30,500",
    "zip_code" => "5700",
    "item_price"=>"100.58",
    "free_method" => "73328" // optional
);

$response = $mp->get("/shipping_options", $params);
print_r($response);
```

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error en el `print_r($response)` al tratar de conectarme con la API de mercadopago, especificamente a `$mp->get("/shipping_options", $params);`:

```
Array ( 
        [status] => 400 
        [response] => Array ( 
                              [message] => Malformed access_token: null 
                              [error] => bad_request 
                              [status] => 400 
                              [cause] => Array ( ) 
                            ) 
)
```

¿Alguien sabe qué pasa? ¿Cómo puedo solucionar ese problema?

Comment: te manda error dónde? en qué línea? cuál es tu código.

Comment: el error lo veo al hacer print_r del $response.

Comment: ¿De dónde obtuviste este código? Enlaza a la página donde encontraste este ejemplo

Comment: https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/use-mercadoenvios/shipping-calculator/

Answer (score 1):

En realidad estas recibiendo esa respuesta porque no estás enviando el token, estas enviando tu client_key y client_secret.